# Router outlet is working but i want to go another page(not into router outlet, a fresh component) with routerLink but instead it goes into routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript

Router Outlet works fine. I'm able to use router-link. But the problem is like i want to go into another page, to another component (not into router outlet), a fresh page i mean. An in that point when i use router-link, it goes into router-outlet again. What should i use to fix this problem.

Main Html

```
<div class="body">
  
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="container">
    <app-sidenav2></app-sidenav2>

    <div class="container2">
      <app-tabs></app-tabs> 
      <div class="routers_container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

(inside app-tabs)

Html

```
<div class="tabs_container_tabs_name_part_holder">
    <button mat-button (click)="toSummary()">Summary</button>
    <button mat-button>Board</button>
    <button mat-button>List</button>
    <button mat-button>Calendar</button>
    <button mat-button>Timeline</button>
    <button mat-button>Forms</button>
    <button mat-button>Issues</button>
    <button mat-button>Reports</button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="project-settings">Project settings</button>
  </div>
```

Ts

```
toSummary() {
    this.router.navigate(['summary']);
  }
```

this is the fine part it is working

but in app-sidenav i want to use router-link but its goin inside router-outlet

```
<label>Projects</label>
        <div class="icon_holder" routerLink="create-project">
            <img src="../../../assets/add.png">
        </div>
```

Comment: Hey buddy, not sure I understand what you are trying to do here. Can you rephrase your question to clearly define the problem you are facing. With what I'm picking so far from your question I would like to believe you need something to do with named router outlets. Update your question so that we understand you better to give more meaningful help.

Comment: It is a bit confusing the description of what you are trying to do, but would maybe child routes work for what you want to do?

Comment: I couldnt express myself well but, @JordiRiera as you said child routes worked very well in my project thank you very much. Also thanks to GeraldChifanzwa i learned a new route concept (named routes). Thank you very much guys.